# How to plot mean of multiple days in R

Tags: r, plot, average, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a netcdf vertical velocity data from ERA5 with one variable (w) but different time steps (17 days) and different pressure levels (27 pressure level) ([data link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mbU8kfpAV_ozcOQza6wGnD-ryA-m_-26/view?usp=sharing)). I am trying to plot the mean of the daily data of a particular level (eg., level 16) and get a single plot in R. I am trying to plot the data with the following code but the generated plot is wrong (it's not doing the mean correctly it seems) and also it's compressed it seems when opened in GIS software.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(sf)
library(raster)

# Open the netCDF file
nc <- nc_open("D:/DATA/2015/VERTICAL_VELOCITY/vv/ee1813a3-f324-4dd6-95e5-c4f1b48ab738.nc")

# Extract the necessary variables
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
lev <- ncvar_get(nc, "plev")
time <- ncvar_get(nc, "time")
VV <- ncvar_get(nc, "w")

# Select level 16
level_index <- 16
level <- lev[level_index]

# Calculate the mean of all time steps at level 16
mean_VV <- apply(VV[, , level_index, ], c(1, 2), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

# Create a new raster object
raster_data <- raster(matrix(mean_VV, nrow = dim(VV)[1], ncol = dim(VV)[2]),
                      xmn = min(lon), xmx = max(lon),
                      ymn = min(lat), ymx = max(lat),
                      crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
# Plot the raster object
plot(raster_data)
```

Any help would be appreciated.